# getting the biggest value from an object's keys

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
var majorityElement = function(nums) {
    let count = {}

    for(i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
        let x = nums[i];
        count[x] ? count[x] + 1 : count[x] = 1
    }

    console.log(count)
    return Object.keys(count).reduce((a,b) => count[a] > count[b] ? a : b)
};
```

So, I don't understand why the count doesn't really work, if I run it the count would look something like this for this array `[3,3,4]`:

```
count{
   3: 1
   4: 1
}
```

Shouldn't it be 3:2 and 4:1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment should be on the left handside so instead of:

```
count[x] ? count[x] + 1 : count[x] = 1
```

try:

```
count[x] = count[x] ? (count[x] + 1) : 1
```

```js
var majorityElement = function(nums) {
    let count = {}

    for(i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
        let x = nums[i];
        count[x] = count[x] ? (count[x] + 1) : 1
    }

    console.log(count)
    return Object.keys(count).reduce((a,b) => count[a] > count[b] ? a : b)
};

console.log(majorityElement([3,3,4]))
```

Comment: @octaviandd you're trying to modify existing `count[x]` value or assign `1` as a default one so `count[x] = ` needs to be the left side of your expression and then on the ride side you can evaluate that value using ternary operator. Otherwise only `count[x] = 1` gets executed which is the reason why your function returns `1` not `2`